# Adding text to a table data cell with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, dom-manipulation

Why this code:

```
row.append($("<td></td>").text("someText"));
```

...isn't working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: not working how? what is `row`? what is the html markup?

Comment: we would like to see your code. please post it

Comment: Make sure `row` is jQuery element. Just try `$(row).append($("<td></td>").text("someText"));`, maybe it will work

Comment: I asked a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655319/inserting-a-table-column-with-jquery) on one of my caffeine-deprived mornings.

Answer (score 10):

The code works fine, as demonstrated with this [**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/axelo). Add */edit* to the URL to see the code. Tested in Firefox 3.5 and IE 6

```
$('button').one('click', function() {
  $('#myTable tr:last').append($("<td></td>").text("someText"));
});
```

Also, you might consider shortening the creation of the cell element to

```
$("<td>someText</td>")
```